# Changing image content scale do not change UI in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've below composable with image inside box (which is inside `LazyColumn`). When I click on box, image scale is changing (which I've verified), but image on UI is not changing. That is, UI stays same, but it should change. What am I missing here?

```
@Composable
fun ImageContent(url: String) {
    var scale by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    val state = rememberTransformableState { zoomChange, _, _ ->
        scale = (scale * zoomChange).coerceIn(1f, 3f)
    }
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(300.dp)
            .padding(start = 4.dp, end = 4.dp)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
            .graphicsLayer(scaleX = scale, scaleY = scale)
            .transformable(state = state)
            .clickable { expanded = !expanded },
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            painter = rememberImagePainter(data = url),
            contentScale = if (expanded) ContentScale.Fit else ContentScale.Crop
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "UI is not changing"? When you click, you change the `expanded` variable, and according to your code, it only changes the `contentScale` of the image (which you've verified). What other changes do you expect?

Comment: yes, `contentScale` is changing, but UI is not upgrading accordingly. For example, when contentScale is changed from Crop to Fit, UI should show image fitted in Image() view, but its staying same as it was in Crop scale. I wants ui change like [this](https://ibb.co/8bjYcjb)

Comment: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlqlh.gif) is how your code works to me, seems exactly what you're looking for, am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, this is want I wants. But same is not happening for me. Maybe due to other parent layouts (LazyColumn)? Same thing is working correctly in other composing screen.

Comment: Maybe, please update your question to  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I've provided answer to my question. kindly check.

Comment: If you need an explanation, you should delete the answer and add this information to your answer. Otherwise, I'm glad you've found the problem.

Comment: Thanks, and i dont need explanation, but just wanted to inform you via comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't mentioned it earlier, but I found the cause of issue and resolved it. `transformations` function was forcing the ui to not change when content scale change

```
Image(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    painter = rememberImagePainter(
        data = url,
        builder = {
            placeholder(R.drawable.ic_filled_placeholder)
            crossfade(300)
            // This line was forcing the ui to not change when content scale change
            transformations(RoundedCornersTransformation(16f))
        }
    ),
    contentScale = if (expanded) ContentScale.Fit else ContentScale.Crop,
    contentDescription = null
)
```